# Auto update using jQuery or AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

I know this is a common question but I cannot seem to get it to work after reading past posts.
I basically want to update my HTML page to display what my PHP page is displaying.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'time.php',
    type: 'GET',
    async: true,
    data: {t: 1},
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function(text){
        document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=text;
    }
});
```

Above is my jQuery Code and it displays on my HTML perfectly.

I have a PHP page that auto refreshes and displays updated time. But the time is my HTML is static.

This is just a test code. I want to implement something that can retrieve new entries from the database (mySQL) whenever a new entry is added and it will be auto displayed to users. How do I go about doing it?

Comment: PHP auto refreshes, but you are only making a single AJAX call, so it will fetch whatever value the PHP file echoes at the time of call. You might want to use `setInterval()` to make timed AJAX calls to the same file.

Comment: I tried to use `setInterval()` before I posted but it didn't work. I guess that was because I called it using `setInterval(startfunction(),1000);`. It should be `setInterval(startfunction,1000);`

Comment: Try that, and see if it works. If it doesn't, post a question :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are updating an HTML, instead of `$.ajax()`, you should use `$.get()`.
See documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Ajax calls uses JSON objects.
If you want to get a whole HMLT texts, you should start using `$.get()`.

If you want to do in a timely manner, put this call in a `setInterval()` function handler.
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp